# How to assign variables to an instance name?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a code in AS3 that works perfectly, but I have mane repeated methods and functions, they are the same but using different instance names, so I would like to replace the instance name with a variable to avoid re-writing too much code.

here is part of my code:

```
urb_mc.urb.select(0);

trace("Urb: " + urb_mc.urb.selectedIndex);
```

I want to replace in this case "urb" with a variable so I tryed this:

```
var estado = currentLabel;
trace("este es mi estado " + estado);// this is ok = "urb"

//now I need to inset the variable in my code:

String(estado)+_mc.String(estado).select(0);//thi is so wrong!

trace("Urb: " + String(estado)+_mc.String(estado).selectedIndex);//thi is so wrong!
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
this[estado+"_mc"][estado].select(0);
trace(this[estado+"_mc"][estado].selectedIndex);
```

Sorry for all the edits!

Thanks for the challenge! I learned there is such a thing as a multidimensional array operator for objects.

**Part 2**

Try this:

var tweenNameArray:Array = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3"]

```
for (var i:int = 0; i > tweenNameArray.length(); i++){
  var myTween:Tween = new Tween();
  myTween.name = String("myTween_" + estado + "_in"); // You may want to try .toString();
}
```

Then referencing the tweens should work like this:

```
Tween(MovieClip(this.stage.getChildByName("myTween_" + estado + "_in")).whateverMethod(); // Try with and without the MovieClip().
```

I will say right now, it is not recommended to do things this way.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that that specific code should only work for children on the same timeline. You may need to change the `this` portion accordingly.

Comment: Its ok, I am already trying that and it works the first time `this[estado+"_mc"]` but the second one `.this[estado]` doesn't. the second one is located inside the first one

Comment: I did not understand the "multidimensional array operator for objects" thing. But it works!!!!! Thanks a lot

Comment: I have another challenge! Can we do the same in a variable? eg `var myTween_urb_in = ....` to `var myTween_estado_in =` ps: does it make any sence?